# Regex Validation for "ASSOC123" in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a task to check an ID that must start with "ASSOC" in uppercase followed by 3 digits. I am a newbie in Java and still learning regex so any help would be welcome!

Comment: You could use something like [this](https://regex101.com/) page for trying regex.

There is also a lot of help regarding regex syntax.

Comment: This isn't a java problem but a regex problem. Go to regex101 like Vladislav Varslavans pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression matches any string that matches the pattern you want: `ASSOC[0-9]{3}`.

If you also want to extract the 3-digit ID as a so-called regex-group from the match, the expression must be as follows: `ASSOC([0-9]{3})`.

The `[0-9]` says here, that we expect a number-character (digit) of 0-9. The curly brackets also express that exactly 3 digits, therefore a 3-digit number is expected.

On Regex101 you also have the possibility to validate different inputs with this regex. Furthermore the regular expression is explained in detail.

- Example 1: https://regex101.com/r/zEN9Gt/1
- Example 2: https://regex101.com/r/zEN9Gt/2

In Java you could test this as follows:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "ASSOC([0-9]{3})";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

final Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher("ASSOC123");
final Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher("Assoc123");

if(matcher1.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
  // Since ASSOC123 is a valid input for the regular expression,
  // matcher1.find() is true and we can output the 3 digit number (attention: group 1!).
  // Group 0 would be the entire expression found, hence "ASSOC123".
}
if(matcher2.find()) {
  // Since "Assoc123" does not match the regular expression, matcher2.find() is false
}
```